# How to query from the list in powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have this response in json format:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "basic": {
            "nodes_table": [
                {
                    "node": "node1.prod.local:80",
                    "state": "active",
                    "weight": 1
                },
                {
                    "node": "node2.prod.local:80",
                    "state": "disabled",
                    "weight": 1
                },
                {
                    "node": "node3.prod.local:80",
                    "state": "disabled",
                    "weight": 1
                },
                {
                    "node": "node4.prod.local:80",
                    "state": "disabled",
                    "weight": 1
                },
                {
                    "node": "node5.prod.local:80",
                    "state": "active",
                    "weight": 1
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do in my powershell script is to find out if given node(s) is available in the nodes_table and get their state. For example:

```
$nodes_table_hostnames = $GetNodesResponse.properties.basic.nodes_table.node
$nodes_table_status = $GetNodesResponse.properties.basic.nodes_table.state

if($nodes_table_hostnames -contains "node1.prod.local:80" -and $nodes_table_status -eq "active")
    {
        Write-Output  "Node matches and is Active"
    }
```

**Problem:**
I am having an issue in getting the state of the "specific" node, so I want to check if "given" node is in the table and that node's state is active/disabled. How would I accomplish that in the script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$Active = $GetNodesResponse.properties.basic.nodes_table |
            Where {$_.Node -eq "node1.prod.local:80" -and $_.state -eq "active"}
If ($Active) {Write-Output  "Node matches and is Active"}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check against multiple strings, use the `-in` operator

```
Where {$_.Node -in "node1.prod.local:80", "node5.prod.local:80" -and $_.state -eq "active"}
```

or you could use the `-like` or `-match` operators to match a pattern as in:

```
Where {$_.Node -like "node[15].prod.local:80" -and $_.state -eq "active"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bruce! Your solution definitely works.